# What is the differece between "to receiving" and "to receive"?

Tags: grammar, american-english, subcontinental-english

I am wondering the differece between "to receiving" and "to receive"? I found in many sentences a simple verb or a "ing" after "to". Though I have explore the following, still I am not clear.

If the work is in continuous form then we use "ing" after "to".
If the work is still to happen then we use simple verb after "to".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Grammatically you cannot use **to receiving** as one unit. But "receiving" can be preceded by by the preposition "to" like:

*I'm looking forward to receiving a letter from my penpal*. -  in this case, **to** is not a marker of an infinitive but part of the combination "to look forward to".

Comment: And "receiving" can be thought of as nounal; a gerund. In that you could substitute,  say, [looking forward to] _Sunday._